# put changes on my development branch to master branch

Tags: git

I created a new branch called `development` branch and made changes to that. The users and myself tested the new code and everything is working fine.

I now want to put all the changes made to our `master` branch so I can implement it to production.

How do I this step?

Comment: The keyword that you are looking for is "merge". Easy way if there were no changes to master: git checkout master followed by git merge development.

Comment: @visibleman can this be done on the github/bitbucket website? or do I need to use remotely via terminal or a GUI git client?

Comment: Yes you can do it either via the web interface, or by the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice remains to perform the merge locally on your computer first, *before* pushhing back to BitBucket remote repo.

```
git checkout master
# make sure master is up-to-date
git pull

git merge development
```

You might have to [resolve some merge conflict](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/), and test again that everything is still working after the merge.
Then push.